# My code is not generating a monthly trend line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph, timeserieschart

I have a Date column and Value column. I did my research on internet and tried every possible thing but it does not shows my the trend line graph. I am totally confused what is happening in my data. I have shared my code below:

```
ggplot(data = New, aes(x = OrderDate, y = TotalAmountWithGST))+
geom_line(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b/%Y")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = OrderDate, y = TotalAmountWithGST)) + 
geom_line()+
theme_minimal()
```

[image]
**I am trying to plot a line graph that shows a monthly trend but somehow I am getting a graph that is similar to bar graph but its not a line graph.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `geom_smooth` to your ggplot code.

It's hard to replicate a working example without sample data but that should get you on the right path.

Comment: Nope. thats not what I am looking for. I need a simple line graph. I have two columns Amount and Date.